# Loss decreases too fast without any predictions in tensorflow object detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I tried to implement object detection on the raccoon dataset following the instructions in this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9). 
Model: ssd_mobilenet_v1 pre-trained on the COCO dataset available in tensorflow model zoo. 
Batch size: 24.

While training, the loss starts at around 12 and decreases to around 4 in less than 20 steps, which is much faster than expected.

However, no boxes are being predicted when eval.py is run.

[image: Training loss]

Comment: So you're looking for help debugging this, or correcting the fit of the model, or something else? (Or just surprised that the output you're getting doesn't match the instructions you're following?) Is there any chance this is an error in the code you've set up? You haven't shown us any code. Is it straight from the blog?

Comment: I cloned the tensorflow object detection api git repo and got it working on windows 10 and followed the exact same instructions as given in the blog. Even after the decrease in loss the confidence level of the boxes shown is minimal and the position is erroneous